# how can i resolve a relative path in both a web/windows app in c#

Tags: c#, relative-path, path

I have an assmebly that will be used in both a desktop app and an asp.net website.

I need to deal with relative paths (local files, not urls) in either situation.

How can i implement this method?

```
string ResolvePath(string path);
```

Under a web envronment, id expect the method to behave like this (where `d:\wwwroot\mywebsite` is the folder iis points at):

```
/folder/file.ext => d:\wwwroot\mywebsite\folder\file.ext
~/folder/file.ext => d:\wwwroot\mywebsite\folder\file.ext
d:\wwwroot\mywebsite\folder\file.ext => d:\wwwroot\mywebsite\folder\file.ext
```

for a desktop environment: (where `c:\program files\myprogram\bin\` is the path of the .exe)

```
/folder/file.ext => c:\program files\myprogram\bin\folder\file.ext
c:\program files\myprogram\bin\folder\file.ext => c:\program files\myprogram\bin\folder\file.ext
```

I'd rather not inject a different `IPathResolver` depending on what state its running in.

How do I detect which environment I'm in, and then what do i need to do in each case to resolve the possibly-relative path?

Thanks

Comment: Relative path to what? A file that's used by your assembly? Is it deployed along with your assembly? You may want to say what you're trying to accomplish, as there may be a better way to do it.

Comment: when in a web environment, relative to the root dir of the iis website  (d:\wwwroot\mywebsite in the example above). and when running as a windows desktop app, the dir that the .exe is in (c:\program files\myprogram\bin\ in the example above).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the original question was answered.

Let assume you want "..\..\data\something.dat" relative to, lets say the executable in "D:\myApp\source\bin\". Using

**System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, relativePath);**

will simply return "D:\myApp\source\bin..\..\data\something.dat" which is also easily obtained by simply concatenating strings.  Combine doesn't resolve paths, it handles trailing backslashes and other trivialities.  He probably wants to run:

**System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("D:\myApp\source\bin..\..\data\something.dat");**

To get the a *resolved* path: "D:\myApp\data\something.dat".

Answer (score 2):

The website binaries are copied to a temp folder when the application runs - so you usually can't get the relative path from the excecuting assembly.

This may not be a sensible way of doing this - but what I did to solve this problem was something like this:

```
if (filepath.StartsWith("~"))
{
   filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filepath);
}
else
{
  filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, filepath);
}
```

This is because on the web version - a relative path has a ~ at the front - so I can tell if it's come from the web.config or the App.config.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in John's comment, relative to what? You can use `System.IO.Path.Combine` method to combine a base path with a relative path like:

```
 System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, relativePath);
```

You can replace `Environment.CurrentDirectory` in the above line with whatever base path you want.

You could store the base path in the configuration file.